# Combining two datetime fields into two separate columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a view that displays events with start and end time. This view should be gathered from an existing table that only has an event time field and event type field.

So the current EventTable looks like this:

```
EventTime       | BooleanField
------------------------------
1/1/2010 6:00AM        1
1/2/2010 6:00AM        0
1/3/2010 6:00AM        1
1/4/2010 6:00AM        1
1/5/2010 6:00AM        0
```

And the result set should look like this

```
StartTime       | EndTime
-----------------------------
1/1/2010 6:00AM   1/2/2010 6:00AM
1/3/2010 6:00AM   1/5/2010 6:00AM
```

So the view should display the periods that the boolean field is true.

Is there a simple solution to achieve this in SQL Server 2008?

Thank you for help!

Comment: I believe any answer is not going to be very simple. SQL Server works best with operations on unordered sets of data. The data set you're looking for depends on an ordering. There is a query that can give what you need, but consider the solution where you retrieve *all* the data and then perform a foreach loop in your application or report builder to get the dataset you need.

Comment: @Michael: Absolutely not.  This is a reasonably straightforward grouping query, which you could also use the windowing functions for.  On a table with millions of rows with several long periods, the SQL version will work just fine if the `EventTime` is indexed, but performance would be abysmal if you `SELECT` all the rows to client.

Comment: I'm just saying I've had to deal with a similar query. And it turns out to be tricky (even with indexing).
The solutions proposed so far include subqueries inside a select clause or join predicate; Or a joins on inequality statements... which might be trouble (depending on context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try something like (*full example*)

```
DECLARE @EventTable TABLE(
        EventTime DATETIME,
        BooleanField INT
)

INSERT INTO @EventTable (EventTime,BooleanField) SELECT '1/1/2010 6:00AM',1 
INSERT INTO @EventTable (EventTime,BooleanField) SELECT '1/2/2010 6:00AM',0 
INSERT INTO @EventTable (EventTime,BooleanField) SELECT '1/3/2010 6:00AM',1 
INSERT INTO @EventTable (EventTime,BooleanField) SELECT '1/4/2010 6:00AM',1 
INSERT INTO @EventTable (EventTime,BooleanField) SELECT '1/5/2010 6:00AM',0

;WITH Dates AS (
        SELECT  *,
                (SELECT MIN(EventTime) FROM @EventTable WHERE EventTime > e.EventTime AND BooleanField = 0) EndDate
        FROM    @EventTable e
        WHERE   BooleanField = 1
)
SELECT  MIN(EventTime) StartDate,
        EndDate
FROM    Dates
GROUP BY EndDate
```

Comment: Gah, beat me to it.  This one's the correct answer though, +1.

Comment: This indeed does produce the correct results. Thank you very much for such quick replies!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(iq.StartTime), iq.EndTime
FROM 
(
    SELECT e1.EventTime AS StartTime, MIN(e2.EventTime) AS EndTime
    FROM EventTable e1
    LEFT JOIN EventTable e2 ON e2.BooleanField = 0 AND e2.EventTime > e1.EventTime
    WHERE e1.BooleanField = 1
    GROUP BY e1.EventTime 
) iq
GROUP BY iq.EndTime
```

This will assure you get only the widest possible intervals for every EndTime you have.  I'm pretty sure it's not possible to simplify this into a single-SELECT query due to the need for two GROUP BY clauses -- even considering the other examples (which use implicit grouping by using two different aggregation functions, so are equivalent to this example).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
  Select s.EventTime StartTime,
         e.EventTime EndTime
  From EventTable s
     Left Join EventTable e 
         On s.BooleanFiels = 1
            And e.BooleanField = 0
            And e.EventTime =
               (Select Min(EventTime) 
                From EventTable 
                Where e.BooleanField = 0
                   And EventTime > s.EventTime)
  Order By s.EventTime
```

Comment: This one skips a day.  Second row should start with 1/3/2010 but starts with 1/4/2010 instead.